# \enquote is not suggested by texstudio autocompletion

Tags: texstudio, csquotes

I use `csquotes` for marking quotes and observe that sometimes texstudio is not autocomplete the `\enquote` command, which is very annoying when one wants to concentrate on writing and a regular routine breaks. Of course, I cannot produce a MWE - because in the MWE it obviously works.

Any suggestions why `\enquote` for a document sometimes works, but sometimes it consistently fails (not just once, but systematically)?

The useless MWE which works....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    silly question
    \enquote{very silly}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not a regular TeXstudio user so take this with a shovel of salt: As far as I understand unless you have explicitly enabled autocomplete for certain packages under *Options > Configure TeXstudio > Completion* TeXstudio will analyse your document and try to figure out which packages you load (and thus which commands to offer in the autocomplete feature), so you are looking for reasons why TeXstudio fails to analyse your packages properly: Maybe it doesn't like weird indentation or if you load `csquotes` via a different package (externalised preamble) ...

Comment: ... A workaround might be to select `csquotes.cwl` as permanently active in *Options > Configure TeXstudio > Completion*.

Comment: The two hints were both useful: I had loaded csquotes in an included file (which probably failed sometimes); the simple solution to tick csquotest.cw. in the options solves the issue I hope permanently! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeXstudio analyses your document in order to offer only auto-completion of commands you can use in your document. I'm not sure exactly how that works, but you may want to look for things that can make it harder for TeXstudio to determine if a package (in this case `csquotes`) was loaded. In particular check for

- Non-standard indentation or other unusual ways you structured your preamble.
- Packages loaded by other packages or via externalised preamble files.

You can make sure a particular set of commands from TeXstudio's auto-completion is always enabled by selecting it in

Options > Configure TeXstudio > Completion > Permanently active completion files

[image: "Options > Configure TeXstudio > Completion" window <code>csquotes.cwl</code> is selected in "Permanently active completion files"]